# How to compare two-dimensional (or nested) Java Arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

From the Java docs for **Arrays.equals(Object[] a, Object[] a2)**:

> Returns **true** if the two specified arrays of Objects are equal to one
>   another. The two arrays are considered equal if both arrays contain
>   the same number of elements, and all corresponding pairs of elements
>   in the two arrays are equal.

But when I ran the program below it is printing `false` as output.

So, Does the mean `equals` method of the `Array` class not work for multidimensional arrays?

What API can I use to achieve `true` as the result in the program below?

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] rows1 = { new String[] { "a", "a" } };

        String[][] rows2 = { new String[] { "a", "a" } };

        System.out.println("Arrays.equals() = " + Arrays.equals(rows1, rows2));

    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepEquals-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object:A-

Comment: @chrylis you should make your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You are comparing two dimensional arrays, which means the elements of these arrays are themselves arrays. Therefore, when the elements are compared (using `Object`'s `equals`), `false` is returned, since `Object`'s `equals` compares `Object` references.

Use `Arrays.deepEquals` instead.

From the Javadoc:

> **boolean java.util.Arrays.deepEquals(Object[] a1, Object[] a2)**
>
> Returns true if the two specified arrays are deeply equal to one another. Unlike the equals(Object [], Object []) method, this method is appropriate for use with nested arrays of arbitrary depth.

Answer (score 8):

`Arrays.deepEquals()`.

Here's why `Arrays.equals` doesn't work.  As the doc says, the arrays have to have the same number of elements, and the elements have to be equals.  The arrays do have the same number of elements: 1.  Each element is another array.

However, those arrays are compared with the regular `equals` method.  And for any object, if the object doesn't override the `equals` method defined for `Object`, then the `equals` method defined for `Object` is used, which is the same as ==.  And arrays don't override `equals` (they also don't override `toString()`, which is why we have to use `Arrays.toString()` to format an array).

`Arrays.deepEquals()` makes a special check for when elements are arrays, and then it uses a recursive `Arrays.deepEquals()` to test those arrays for equality.

Answer (score 0):

It is not working as expected because you are initializing two different objects with `new`.

From Java Docs:

> `boolean java.util.Arrays.equals(Object[] a, Object[] a2)`
>
> Returns true if the two specified arrays of Objects are equal to one
>   another. The two arrays are considered equal if both arrays contain
>   the same number of elements, and all corresponding pairs of elements
>   in the two arrays are equal. Two objects e1 and e2 are considered
>   equal if (e1==null ? e2==null : e1.equals(e2)). In other words, the
>   two arrays are equal if they contain the same elements in the same
>   order. Also, two array references are considered equal if both are
>   null.
>
> Parameters: a one array to be tested for equality a2 the other array
>   to be tested for equality Returns: true if the two arrays are equal

Answer (score 0):

Please refer **Arrays.equals vs  Arrays.deepEquals**

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepEquals(java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object[])